# querySelector как поместить внутри блока span?

Tags: javascript, валидация, span, queryselectorall, queryselector

Данный скрипт формирует и выводит поле ошибки в форме:

```
var message = field.form.querySelector('.input__error#error-for-' + id );

    if (!message) {
        message = document.createElement('span');
        message.className = 'input__error';
        message.id = 'error-for-' + id;

        // If the field is a radio button or checkbox, insert error after the label
        var label;
        if (field.type === 'radio' || field.type ==='checkbox') {
            label = field.form.querySelector('label[for="' + id + '"]') || field.parentNode;
            if (label) {
                label.parentNode.insertBefore( message, label.nextSibling );
            }
        }

        // В противном случае вставьте его после поля
        if (!label) {
            field.parentNode.insertBefore( message, field.nextSibling );
        }

    }
```

В таком виде:

```
<span class="input__error" id="error-for-form-input-names">Заполните поле.</span>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как поместить это поле внутрь блока span в шаблоне, как показано на примере ниже?

```
<span class="input__text">
      <span class="input__label">Имя</span>
      <span class="input__error" id="error-for-form-input-names">Заполните поле.</span>
</span>
```

Спасибо

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/paveell/2d8n5o4d/6/

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вот так?

```
var container = document.querySelector('.input__text');
var message = document.createElement('span');
message.id = 'error-for-form-input-names';
message.classList.add('input__error');
message.innerHTML = 'Заполните поле.';
container.appendChild(message);
```

Comment: Обернул в container, но теперь все поля выдает в один блок

Comment: Строка 97 https://jsfiddle.net/paveell/2d8n5o4d/6/

Comment: @paveell в вашем случае скорее всего вместо container.appendChild(message) нужно написать field.parentNode.insertBefore(message, field);